# Select and disable each input field within a form, wrapped in a table in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I am disabling a form based on a checkbox...

I am having trouble adding the disabled attribute.

here is what I got so far:
HTML:

```
<table id="shipInfoTable">
  <tr>
   <td>Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Javascript selector/attribute manipulation(jquery):

```
$("#shipInfoTable tbody tr td input").each(function(index, item){
    item.attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Chrome Dev Console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attr'`

When I alert out the `item` within the `.each()` it alerts `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Not quite sure how to select the input element properly.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function will not give you a jQuery object. It should be:

```
$("#shipInfoTable input").each(function(index, item){
    $(item).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

(note that I also simplified your selector, it still works)
If you aren't doing anything eles with each item, this will work as well:

```
$("#shipInfoTable input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Please note: in current versions of jQuery, this was changed to `.prop("disabled", true)`. I'm pretty sure `attr` didn't do was was intended anyway.

Answer (score 4):

....

```
$("#shipInfoTable tbody tr td input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the lack of $() in the .each() function...

```
$("#shipInfoTable tbody tr td input").each(function(index, item){
    $(item).attr("disabled", true);
});
```